# Inductive step determinant proof

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I need help with this inductive step. Assume that the determinant function for an N $x$ N matrix exists and fulfills the three properties of a determinant. For $\{v_1, ... , v_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, define $v_i^0 = \{0, v_{i,0}, ... v_{i,n}\}$. I want to show that for any determinant function,

det$(e_1 , v_1^0, ..., v_n^0) = $ det$(v_1, ... , v_n)$

I don't really have any idea how to do this without using the specific determinant formula, but I'm supposed to be able to prove it from just the 3 basic determinant properties.

Comment: What specific properties are you talking about?

Comment: That determinant of standard basis vectors is 1, that the determinant is alternating, and that it is linear in each of its arguments

Comment: It looks to me like you are allowed to develop it (check out https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcul_du_d%C3%A9terminant_d%27une_matrice , the part with the $A_{i,j}$). Develop it along the first colomn, and you have your result. I didn't find the english equivalent, sorry about that, but formulas don't need any translation